# Insert statement error on pageload event in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom page named "failed" in my WordPress site. What I am trying to do is after this page load it will insert data in payError Table in date and type column. date is a date datatype column and type is of varchar data type.

For this I have written following code. But that page is not working and giving error "This page isn’t working". What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: failed
 */
get_header();

?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Payment Cancelled </p>
            <?php
            global $wpdb;

            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            $type = "Perfect Money";

            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "payError";
            $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
            'date' => $today,
            'type' => $type
            ));
            ?> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You had a `}` extra. . I have removed that . . if you can try with this code now

Comment: its working on your edit thanks but not inserting any data

Comment: I think some error is on your page. . you can use `WP_DEBUG` to troubleshoot. .change `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` to `true` in your `wp-config.php` and try again. .  https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/

Comment: after setting debugging true it is showng  following error               WordPress database error: [Table 'foxhyvge_wp503.wp_payError' doesn't exist]
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_payError`  I have named my table as payError . Am I needed to add prefix like wp before table name

Comment: I think all of tables in your DB have "wp_" prefix like "wp_post" etc. . but your table "payError" does not have "wp_" prefix .. so you must rename table "payError" to "wp_payError" and it should work

Comment: i see wp_ prefix is given from wp-config file with this line $table_prefix  = 'wp_';

Comment: hi thanks I have added prefix wp_ before it and its working.

Comment: Comments are not for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think some error is on your page. . you can use `WP_DEBUG` to troubleshoot. .change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to true in your `wp-config.php` and try again. . it will help you to see errors and debug

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/debugging-wordpress-how-to-use-wp_debug/